# Please add syntax highlighting to review queues

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, review

The beta review queues ([close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), [first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts), [low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)) seem to have syntax highlighting disabled. I see no color on code on Stack Overflow in Chrome 21.

Please activate syntax highlighting in all review queues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posts in the review queue have syntax highlighting now. Thanks.